# iterating over columns in a list of tuples with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, iterator, tuples

I have a list of `List<Tuple<string[], double[]>>`

```
List<Tuple<string[], double[]>> tt = new List<Tuple<string[], double[]>>();

var t1 = new Tuple<string[], double[]>(
    new string[] { "java", "c#", "nn" },
    new double[] { 2, 3, 0 });

var t2 = new Tuple<string[], double[]>(
    new string[] { "java", "c#", "nn" },
    new double[] { 0, 3, 1 });

var t3 = new Tuple<string[], double[]>(
    new string[] { "java", "c#", "nn" },
    new double[] { 2, 1, 0 });

tt.Add(t1);
tt.Add(t2);
tt.Add(t3);
```

Lets say I want to divide each element in the `double[]` by the total counts non-zero `count`s in the columns. I would get the following results

```
t1 2/2, 3/3 0/1
t2 0/2, 3/3 1/1   
t3 2/2, 1/3 0/1
```

Here is what I tried but it counts the row totals instead of the columns

```
var XX = (from tuples in tt
          let rows = tuples.Item2.ToArray()
          let result = rows.Select(x => x/rows.Count(i => i != 0)).ToArray()
         select new Tuple<string[], double[]>(tuples.Item1, result)
       ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be achieved with the following LINQ query:

```
List<Tuple<string[], double[]>> result = tt.Select(x => 
    Tuple.Create(
        x.Item1, 
        x.Item2.Select((y, i) => y / tt.Count(z => z.Item2[i] > 0))
    .ToArray())).ToList();
```

---

Here are the resultant doubles printed to console:

[image]